# Keep running program until user input exit

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

My main function

```
int main(){
Postfix post;
char size=100;
char infix[size];
string get_input=" ";


  cout<<"Input Infix";
  cin>>infix;
    int  size=strlen(infix);
    char postfix[size];
    post.infix_to_postfix(infix, postfix, size);
    cout<<"\nInfix Expression is:"<<"  "<<infix;
    cout<<"\nPostfix Expression is:"<<"  "<<postfix;
    cout<<endl;
```

The program converts infix to postfix notation with stacks. My question is, is there a way to keep looping until the user does not want to. 
similar to this

```
   int n;
  cin>>n;

  while (n!=0){
  // keep doing whatever
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
while(cin >> infix){
    // your code here....
}
```

the program will stop taking user input when user presses "ctrl+Z"

Answer (score 3):

Below are the two ways you can do this..
first of all is to would suggest to use `std::string` it would make your life easy. Try to include it in your coding habit..

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty())
{
    //write your logic here
}
```

To break the loop user has to press `enter`

Second way

```
std::string str;
while(std::cin>>str)
{
//write your logic here
}
```

To break the loop press `ctrl+D`